# How to create a HTML world map with GeoDjango?

Tags: python, html, django, gis, geodjango

The [GeoDjango tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/) explains how to insert world borders into a spatial database.

I would like to create a world Map in HTML with these data, with both `map` and `area` tags. [Something like that](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html).

I just don't know how to retrieve the coordinates for each country (required for the `area`'s `coords` attribute).

```
from world.models import WorldBorders

for country in WorldBorders.objects.all():
    print u'<area shape="poly" title="%s" alt="%s" coords="%s" />' % (v.name, v.name, "???")
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In the worldborders example, the attribute `mpoly` is where the geographic polygon is actually stored.

In your example, you're going to want to access `v.mpoly`

You're not going to be able to use it directly however because `mpoly` is itself a `MultiPolygon` [field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#multipolygon). Consider a country like Canada that has a bunch of islands, each island and the main landmass is a polygon. So to arrive at your points and a complete description of Canada's borders you need to:

1. Iterate over the polygons inside of multipolygon. Each polygon corresponds to an area (so your assumption in the example of one area per country is wrong).
2. Iterate over the points inside of each [polygon](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#polygon).
3. Convert your [point](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#point) coordinates (latitude/longitude) into the coordinates used by your svg graphic.

Comment: I understood your logic, thank you ! When you say "Convert lat/lon to coordinates for SVG graphic", do you mean I just have to make a simple addition ?

Answer (score 0):

To use lat/lon in an SVG, you need to project them into pixel (x/y) space.  A simple transformation might look like this:

```
>>> x = (lon + 180) / 360 * image_width
>>> y = (90 - lat) / 180 * image_height
```

For an image where `image_width == 2 * image_height`, this will give you something like the map at the link posted (which looks like an [equirectangular projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection)).

To use a different projection (e.g. [Mercator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection)), use the [GEOSGeometry.transform](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.transform) method in GeoDjango before applying the transform.